# How to get Solana instruction data from transaction object

Tags: transactions, web3.js, transfer, instructions

*Disclaimer: I asked this on SO and also in Discord, but was directed here, so here I am...*

I'm doing a simple transaction with a single `transfer` instruction for 0,1 SOL from one account to another. Then in my backend service I want to get the transaction and verify the data it carries - specifically that a transfer has been made for 0,1 SOL.

I use [getTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTransaction) with the tx signature and get a response like this:

```
{
  message: Message {
    header: {
      numReadonlySignedAccounts: 0,
      numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts: 1,
      numRequiredSignatures: 1
    },
    accountKeys: [ [PublicKey], [PublicKey], [PublicKey] ],
    recentBlockhash: '9S44wiNxXZSdP5VTG6nvaumUJBiUW1DGUXmhVfuhwTMh',
    instructions: [ [Object] ],
    indexToProgramIds: Map(1) { 2 => [PublicKey] }
  },
  signatures: [
    '8ykRq1XtgrtymXVkVhsWjaDrid5FkKzRPJrarzJX9a6EArbEUYMrst6vVC6TydDRG4sagSciK6pP5Lw9ZDnt3RD'
  ]
}
```

So, I dig into `message.instructions` and find the following object:

```
{ accounts: [ 0, 1 ], data: '3Bxs411Dtc7pkFQj', programIdIndex: 2 }
```

Ok, so `data` is the `base58`-encoded string `'3Bxs411Dtc7pkFQj'`. I decode that from base58 (using [bs58](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58)), but that only gives me a Uint8Array, which I am not really sure how to convert into a JS object.

I can see in [the tx in Solscan](https://solscan.io/tx/8ykRq1XtgrtymXVkVhsWjaDrid5FkKzRPJrarzJX9a6EArbEUYMrst6vVC6TydDRG4sagSciK6pP5Lw9ZDnt3RD?cluster=devnet) that the `data` information is decoded into `hex`:

[image]

And I can also get this same info in my script:

```
---> Instructions:
{ accounts: [ 0, 1 ], data: '3Bxs411Dtc7pkFQj', programIdIndex: 2 }

---> Instructions Data:
base58: 3Bxs411Dtc7pkFQj
hex: 0200000000e1f50500000000
```

But not sure what to do next. How do I get the actual info inside the data?

So, I guess the question is: **How to decode the instruction data into a JS object?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different questions here.

> Then in my backend service I want to get the transaction and verify the data it carries - specifically that a transfer has been made for 0,1 SOL.

When you perform a `getTransaction()`, it actually returns all involved account balances before and after the transaction in `meta` field:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "err": null,
    "fee": 5000,
    "innerInstructions": [],
    "postBalances": [499998932500, 26858640, 1, 1, 1],
    "postTokenBalances": [],
    "preBalances": [499998937500, 26858640, 1, 1, 1],
    "preTokenBalances": [],
    "status": {
      "Ok": null
    }
  },
  "slot": 430,
  "transaction": {
    "message": {
      "accountKeys": [
        "3UVYmECPPMZSCqWKfENfuoTv51fTDTWicX9xmBD2euKe",
        "AjozzgE83A3x1sHNUR64hfH7zaEBWeMaFuAN9kQgujrc",
        "SysvarS1otHashes111111111111111111111111111",
        "SysvarC1ock11111111111111111111111111111111",
        "Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
      ],
```

For example, in the above sample response, index 0 of `preBalances` and `postBalances` indicates a -5000 lamports change. This corresponds to index 0 account in `accountKeys` so now we know `3UVYmECPPMZSCqWKfENfuoTv51fTDTWicX9xmBD2euKe` had 5000 SOLs deducted (presumably the transaction fee).

You can use this technique to find all the account balance changes as part of your transaction.

PS. Btw the "Account Balances" tables in most explorers are just parsing these values into a table.

PPS. There is also a `getParsedTranscation()` that will make that structure a little bit more friendly.

---

> So, I guess the question is: How to decode the instruction data into a JS object?

This is a different kettle of fish. And I should note that instruction data is no guarantee that the transfer happened. Think of it as the request that was sent.

But lemme answer that general question anyway:

To decode instruction data, you need to know its layout. This layout is defined in the on-chain program so if you have access to that, then you can redefine it in JavaScript, using `@solana/buffer-layout`.

In your case, you are using a well-known program and Solana Labs already created a JavaScript decoder for it in `@solana/web3.js`. See https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/SystemInstruction.html#decodeTransfer

Comment: `getParsedTranscation()` is pretty much what I needed, I guess.

Comment: for some more info on ix decoding: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-do-you-convert-the-byte-array-returned-as-data-for-a-given-instruction-int/736#736

Answer (score 3):

We implemented similar logic as part of the [Solana Pay SDK](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/653bc50272/core/README.md)

The thought process is as follows:

1. get the transaction
2. get the pre and post balances
3. validate the change we expected happened

```
const response = await connection.getTransaction(signature);
const message = response.transaction.message;
const meta = response.meta;
const accountIndex = message.accountKeys.findIndex((pubkey) => pubkey.equals(recipient));
const preBalance = new BigNumber(meta.preBalances[accountIndex] || 0).div(LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
const postBalance = new BigNumber(meta.postBalances[accountIndex] || 0).div(LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)

if (postAmount.minus(preAmount).lt(amount)) throw new Error('amount not transferred');
```

Comment: So, the `data` prop inside the `instructions` is useless in this use-case? What's the point of that object then?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's useless, but for your use-case, there's a more sure way of verifying the transfer. More details on the data: https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#instruction-data. You could also look into use cases for signing a message, "can" be more robust than manually comparing the data. https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/537/50