# Parsing instructions in Rust

Tags: anchor, instructions, idl, borsh

I'm exploring a service called [Streaming Fast](https://github.com/streamingfast) that parses instruction data by program ID.

I'm currently listening to the Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111 program id and I see:

```
{
  "instructions": [
    {
      "programId": "Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111",
      "accounts": [
        "9LU56oFPjrD49uzVVeFDejif2haUSDDEUtCPc1VdhmT3",
        "SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111"
      ],
      "data": "1111pb5URbvJnwibmx1CAYsJEUNg2TxcPwouftpwg9tiKfjuLZa9cRMur3qmSgvkEE7m7FoZ2PWmpFzKarnuo9MMDzcL1zgevEJqc11DfGVza97cXpsGWbZ3GmVX2VJmuWQ5DtHV23RFZvWDsoWnBRqxoc3uy"
    },
    {
      "programId": "Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111",
      "accounts": [
        "9LU56oFPjrD49uzVVeFDejif2haUSDDEUtCPc1VdhmT3",
        "J2nUHEAgZFRyuJbFjdqPrAa9gyWDuc7hErtDQHPhsYRp",
        "SysvarC1ock11111111111111111111111111111111",
        "SysvarStakeHistory1111111111111111111111111",
        "StakeConfig11111111111111111111111111111111",
        "J4QeXzYYejdY4qBeFUQb5KzwaDMvZPbYywhUTPQfRXna"
      ],
      "data": "3xyZh"
    }
  ]
}
```

My understanding from [how to decode data instructions with javascript](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/how-to-decode-data-instructions-with-javascript) is that I need to use the IDL to parse this data, I guess to get the arguments?

In JS/TS it is:

```
import * as borsh from 'borsh';
import bs58  from "bs58";
const schema = { 'struct': { 'discriminator': 'u64', 'buyerPrice': 'u64', 'tokenSize': 'u64', 'buyerStateExpiry': 'i64', 'buyerCreatorRoyaltyBp': 'u16', 'extraArgs': {'array': {'type':'u8'}} } };
const data = "UEVYJrzmev2UQ1cVQ8mBufZjnj8LT83s1ukeQvg1kERm5M7F3oaX";
const decoded = borsh.deserialize(schema, Buffer.from(bs58.decode(data)));
console.log(decoded);
```

Am I thinking about this correctly? Is there a way to see logs here or is this just the instruction argument parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stake program is a bit unique because it doesn't have an IDL.

On the other hand, `@solana/web3.js` provides instruction decoders out of the box for you. Given the instruction data, you can do:

```
const instructionType = StakeInstruction.decodeInstructionType(instructionData);
switch (instructionType) {
    case 'Authorize':
        return StakeInstruction.decodeAuthorize(instructionData);
    case 'Deactivate':
        return StakeInstruction.decodeDeactivate(instructionData);
    // etc etc
}
```

And you'll need to do this for every instruction at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/dd2096e6fbd86b1ea524e089853e5f2a9754472b/packages/library-legacy/src/programs/stake.ts#L447

Inspiration taken from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/dd2096e6fbd86b1ea524e089853e5f2a9754472b/packages/library-legacy/test/program-tests/stake.test.ts#L98

Comment: got it - this is helpful - do you know if there are any rust equivalent code examples for parsing such instructions? I'm more thinking about crates / libraries - the other logic I can transcribe pretty easily

Comment: Certainly! Check out `solana-transaction-status`, which has a `parse_stake` module https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/transaction-status/src/parse_stake.rs